# Smooth application between ${\mathbb{S}}^2$ and ${\mathbb{R}P}^{2}$

Tags: general-topology, differential-geometry, differential-topology, geometric-topology

Prove that there is not a smooth application $s: {\mathbb{R}P}^{2} \rightarrow \mathbb{S}^2$ such that composing by the canonic projection $\pi: \mathbb{S}^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}P^2$ is equal to the identity in $\mathbb{R}P^2$.

Attempt of proof:
The smooth map $\pi \circ s$ implies that the differential is the identity 2x2 matrix. But this means that the compositions of the differentials $s$ and $\pi$ is the identity 2x2 matrix. However, $\pi$ is not inyective; therefore, its differential has a 0-row, so we get a contradiction.

But, I'm not sure if this attempt with differentials is correct.

Comment: I am sure you mean that $\pi \circ s = id$ is impossible. That $s \circ \pi = id$ is impossible is trivial because $\pi$ is not injective.

Comment: Do you know the deRham cohomology of $S^2$ and $\mathbb RP^2$? edit: overkill

Comment: First, you mean to look at $\pi\circ s$. Second, $d\pi$ is an isomorphism at each point.

Comment: @DanielTeixeira No, I don't :(. I'm trying to prove it using tangent spaces and differentials.

Comment: @TedShifrin So, I should look at that composition in order to prove that it is a diffeomorphism (which means that the differential is an isomorphism at each point). But then, how can I find the contradiction? (Thx btw)

Comment: No, you want to prove such an $s$ cannot exist. $\pi$ is a local diffeomorphism. This is really a consequence of basic algebraic topology (fundamental group) or basic differential topology (mod 2 intersection theory). I don’t see a proof using just the derivative.

Comment: I would argue that a derivative only proof is hopeless because these two spaces are indistinguishable by local data, which is all the derivative knows about. You could try to say something about the global structure of the derivatives, but then we're really back to algebraic / differential topology.

Comment: You might try to show the projection from the unit _circle_ $S^{1}$ to the _real projective line_ $\mathbf{RP}^{1}$ (viewed as the circle of radius $1/2$ centered at $(1/2, 0)$, a.k.a. the polar graph $r = \cos\theta$) has no section. This looks like straightforward trigonometry. Then argue contrapositively that a section of the projection $S^{2} \to \mathbf{RP}^{2}$, restricted to $\mathbf{RP}^{1}$, gives a section of the projection $S^{1} \to \mathbf{RP}^{1}$.

Comment: If there is such a map, then $\mathbb{R}P^2$ can be embedded in $S^2$ since the projection $S^2\to \mathbb{R}P^2$ is a $\mathbb{Z}/2$ (which is discrete)-bundle. But it is impossible.